# Ruby variable in jquery show/hide block

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Right now this jquery works just fine:

```
:javascript
    $( "#catExpander1" ).click(function() {
      $( "#category1" ).toggle( "fast", function() {
      });
    });
```

But of course it has a big problem: it can't be reused to show/hide other divs. How would I replace the hard-coded ids with variables?

**For context:**
I'm currently using this in a rails app to show/hide subcategories under their parent category, which are all inside of a side-bar category navigation list. The only way I can currently think to do this is create a separate jquery block for each category and subcategory, but of course this is a *horrible* approach because it requires lots of repeating, is not reusable, etc.

Comment: It sounds like you can accomplish this using classes and traversal functions, but I think we'll need to see some html to give a better answer.

Comment: `".#category1"` is a pretty broken selector, I can't believe that's doing anything for you currently.

Comment: You don't need ruby here. using data attributes, or binding the $.toggle() to classes you'll add to the elements you wanna toggle is the proper way of doing it. You can use ruby to attach the class, or better: create a service that returns a json of the hidden elements, and apply it when the dom is ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be smart about it, use one of the many existing libraries for collapsable. [Bootstrap has a good one](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse).

If you really want to roll your own solution...

Typically you'd link the related DOM nodes together via the `href` of the button (assuming it's a link), or a `data-` attribute. It's important that the DOM itself convey the relationship between the elements, both for the semantic integrity of your document and because it's the best way of accomplishing this with a minimal amount of JavaScript.

You can then write a generic click handler which knows what element to show/hide based on which element was clicked.

Finally, all of your expander-buttons would be given a class, like `expandable`, which you'd then use to bind all the buttons with a single `$('.expandable').click` call, or via a single `on` call if they'll be dynamically added to the DOM.

The result would look something like this:

```
<a href="#category1" class="expandable">Expand Category 1!</a>
<div id="category1">
Item 1
Item 2
</div>
```

And...

```
$(".expandable").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $($(this).attr('href')).toggle( "fast" );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use the HTML data attribute. For example, for every expander, add a data attribute that references the ID to expand.

Assuming the expander is an image.

```
<img src="..." data-target="category1" class="expander" />
```

Then in your code

```
$(".expander").click(function() {
  $("#" + $(this).data("target")).toggle( "fast", function() {
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You may add a mutual css class to all categories e.g. `category` and use events delegation:

```
$( "#catExpander1" ).on('click', '.category', function() {
  $(this).toggle('fast')
});
```

Comment: This works great. Awarded the correct answer to @meagar, however, because of his thorough explanation. Went ahead and gave your an up-vote.